# пользовательские переменные в SQL (MySQL) запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, select, переменные

Чтобы не писать несколько раз название таблицы, можно использовать алиас:

```
select a.* from `genome-2015-05-homo` a where <...>
```

можно определить пользовательскую переменную, чтобы задавать её параметром для сложного запроса:

```
set @chr="8";
select b.* from (
select a.* from `genome-2015-05-homo` a where `chr`=@chr <...>) b
where b.`param` = @chr <...>
```

Но можно ли задавать имена таблиц до select, чтобы потом использовать их, как параметры? То есть хотелось бы:

```
set @p_table = `genome-2015-05-homo`;
set @k_table = `genome-2015-05-homo-genes-only`;
select position from @p_table where <...>
union all
select position from @k_table where <...>
```

Ан, нет - выдаётся ошибка. И кавычки разные пробовал, и @p_table заключал в апострофы - не получалось. Неужели нельзя задавать имена таблиц до запроса?

Comment: *Неужели нельзя задавать имена таблиц до запроса?* Использовать значения переменных для формирования имени таблицы в тексте запроса - нельзя. Только в рамках Prepared Statement - но это вряд ли будет проще.

Comment: @Akina Жалко, получается, каждый раз при применении запроса необходимо ручками пройтись по нему и поменять названия таблиц...

Comment: Напиши хранимку, с использованием динамического SQL.

Comment: "_получается, каждый раз при применении запроса необходимо ручками пройтись по нему и поменять названия таблиц_". Да, так получается при неправильной структуре БД. Раз запрос может работать при изменении имен таблиц, значит у вас все таблицы имеют одинаковую структуру. Если вы создадите одну общую таблицу и добавите в нее колонку, например TabID и еще таблицу-справочник где будут даваться имена этим ID, то у вас запрос превратиться в `select position from @p_table where (TabID=1 and ...) OR (TabID=2 and ...)` (и еще от union избавитесь).

Comment: И при этом нужные ID можно получать либо заранее запросами вроде `select @id1:=TabID from справочник where name='genome-2015-05-homo'`, либо напишите это подзапросами в основном запросе и будете в начале в переменных задавать имена объектов, как и хотели

Comment: Хотя при ваших объемах данных, хранение TabID к каждой записи может оказаться слишком дорогим удовольствием ... Надо смотреть сколько это займет и как быстрее будет работать. Скорость часто важнее, правильной организации БД и удобной работы с ней. Но часто правильная организация повышает и скорость ...